# Accessing multiple sites via FTP

Tags: multisite

I've installed wordpress MU, and established a different site in my domain/dev/sitename -- but I want to then install a theme on that site, and edit it directly. However, my FTP only shows the main Wordpress installation. How do I get at the /sitename subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get to the `/sitename` sub-directory. You install the theme in the `themes` sub-directory, and enable it for all sites. WPMU doesn't have an out-of-the-box capability to enable a theme for one site only, but I there might be plugins that give that functionality.

Comment: Yes, you can enable the theme for one site only, out of the box... But, are you refering to WPMU or to Multisite?

Comment: @brasofilo I'm referring to [WPMU](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU), thanks for helping me clarify.